# Ionic capacitor ads

Tags: ionic-framework, ads, capacitor

I am developing an Ionic Capacitor application, and I am wondering which plugin is the best way to go in terms of ads?

I have seen that the cordova-plugin-admobpro is not supported, and that Capacitor has its own community [ad plugin](https://github.com/capacitor-community/admob). I do not know how good community plugins are, which is why I am asking here.

Also, I have used [this plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/admob-free) in the past, but it is a Cordova plugin, it also does not say it is not supported in the capacitor know issues page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Capacitor Community plugins are all endorsed by the CapacitorJS team and so they guarantee (by association) a certain level quality.

It used to be that plugins were maintained in independent Git repositories which you would simply select and install but the Ionic/Capacitor team are moving more towards an official channel to encourage package maintenance which previous plugins have often struggled with.

So to answer your question, community plugins are good and seemingly reasonably well maintained.